# rhosync not starting!

Tags: rhodes, rhomobile

I installed rhodes as per the tutorial on the website and i also installed rhosync
Now when i try to start rhosync then i get error

```
[12:06:07 PM 2011-02-23] Rhosync Server v2.1.1 started...
 <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- application (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from config.ru:27:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:1:in `new'
    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `parse_file'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:162:in `app'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:248:in `wrapped_app'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:213:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:100:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/rackup:19:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/rackup:19:in `<main>'
```

[EOF - dtach terminating]

Is this a Path Issue??...If it is then how to set correct path???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching to Ruby version 1.8.7

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ruby 1.9.1+ then you have to change your config.ru

replace "require 'application'"  with require './application'
because "$: doesn't include the current direcotry."

http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2010/08/18/ruby-1-9.2-released/

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following things :

- make sure you have started redis.
- you are in same directory as your application

Cheers
Abhishek Nalwaya

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to install rhosync in windows with the msi installer ([download page](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhosync/downloads)), then start the redis.